# Selenium not finding list of sections with classes?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to get a list of games on

```
https://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/gold#gameswithgold
```

According to Firefox's dev console, it seems that I found the correct class: https://i.imgur.com/M6EpVDg.png

In fact, since there are 3 games, I am supposed to get a list of 3 objects with this code: https://pastebin.com/raw/PEDifvdX (the wait is so Seleium can load the page)

But in fact, Selenium says it does not exist: https://i.imgur.com/DqsIdk9.png

I do not get what I am doing wrong. I even tried css selectors like this

```
listOfGames = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("section.m-product-placement-item f-size-medium context-game gameDiv")
```

Still nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option with a selector that isn't looped over and changed-- also one that's less dependent on the page structure and a little easier to read:

```
//a[starts-with(@data-loc-link,'keyLinknowgame')]//h3
```

Here's sample code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = f"https://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/gold#gameswithgold"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
listOfGames = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@data-loc-link,'keyLinknowgame')]//h3")
for game in listOfGames:
    try:
        print(game.text)
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        pass
```

If you're after more than just the title, remove the //h3 selection:

```
//a[starts-with(@data-loc-link,'keyLinknowgame')]
```

And add whatever additional Xpath you want to narrow things down to the content/elements that you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get three different games so you need to give different element path or you can use some sort of loop like this one

```
i = 1
while i < 4:
    link = f"//*[@id='ContentBlockList_11']/div[2]/section[{i}]/a/div/h3"
    listGames = str(driver.find_element_by_xpath(link).text)
    print(listGames)
    i += 1
```

you can use this kind of loop in some places where there is slight different in xpath,css or class

in this way it will loop over web element one by one and get the list of game

as you are trying to get name I think so you need to put `.text` which will only get you the name nothing else